# Advice - New View for Bundled Products

Tags: product-view, bundled-product

I'd like to have a different view - that you could select in the product admin panel - for bundle products.

Instead of the default view I'd like to do something more visual with the images of the products that user can select in the bundle, more interactive.

I'm struggling trying to do it in the right way regarding Magento structure. What would you recommend? What do you think is the best way to do that?

I know I need to create a new module, I have already created it and I can select it in the product admin panel. But I'm not sure if the better way is create a new block, or a new page template, or a new product view...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question fully correct. But I can tell you, that I made a new template (called something like "...bundle") solely for bundles > edited and indivdualised it to my needs > and selected this new template within the a products' section "layout" (or "design", I am using a not-english interface on my projects)

This seems to work out quite good, because in this way I can also manipulate other indirect templates and layout like the minicart, the notifications and so on - solely for bundled products.